# How to split a list of lists dynamically with next line separator

Tags: python, list

My list of lists looks like this:

```
list_of_lists = [['England', '90.0%'], ['Scotland', '10.0%']]
```

I would like to have this output:

```
England, 90.0%
Scotland, 10.0%
```

I have tried unpacking the list of lists and printing using the following:

```
a,b = list_of_lists
print(a,'\n',b)
```

but I would like to print them dynamically based on the length of the list_of_lists. So if my list_of_lists is len(x) then I want to `print(x[0],'\n\',...,x[i])`

Comment: what is the link to `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` the elements per row using `', '` as separator, then `join` the rows with a newline and `print`:

```
list_of_lists = [['England', '90.0%'], ['Scotland', '10.0%']]

print('\n'.join(map(', '.join, list_of_lists)))
```

output:

```
England, 90.0%
Scotland, 10.0%
```

Comment: this helped me, thanks. i was trying to do everything in one line with no loops and this was the first answer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `for` loop?

```
for row in list_of_lists:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use unpacking of a generator that formats each entry and use a new line as the print separator:

```
print(*(f'{c}, {p}' for c,p in list_of_lists),sep='\n')
```

*This supports different data types and gives you full control over the order, spacing, alignment and delimiters*

If your data is only made up of strings that you want to separate with commas, you can use join instead of a format string:

```
print(*map(', '.join,list_of_lists),sep='\n') # only works with string data
```